# Dependency injection in create() method of block plugin with derivatives

Tags: plugins, dependency-injection

I am trying to extend the `menu_block` module to allow it to work with domains (via the `domain` module). In order to do this I am extending the `MenuBlock` class, and trying to access the `domain.negotiator` service from within `getDerivativeID()`. I am using the `create()` method to inject the service and store it to a `$domainNegotiator` property as follows:

```
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    $instance = parent::create($container, $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $instance->domainNegotiator = $container->get('domain.negotiator');
    return $instance;
  }
```

When I attempt to call `$this->domainNegotiator` from within `getDerivativeID()` I get an error stating the property doesn't exist and I therefore cannot access methods on it. In debugging I was able to trace the issue to `MenuBlock::defaultConfiguration()` calling `$this->getDerivativeID()`.

Default configuration is set in `__construct()` inside `BlockPluginTrait` (called in `BlockBase`), so ultimately it boils up to being called in my class's `create()` method.

I am able to work around this issue by using a non-injected version of the service in my `getDerivativeID()` method, however this isn't a great practice:

```
$active_domain = \Drupal::service('domain.negotiator')->getActiveDomain();
```

Is there a way to inject dependencies so they are available before calling `parent::create()` in my class's `create()` method?

Comment: Simplest would probably be to do what core does when it's not sure if a service has been injected, e.g. [`ControllerBase::entityTypeManager()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Controller%21ControllerBase.php/function/ControllerBase%3A%3AentityTypeManager/9.3.x)

Answer (score 3):

The Drupal plugin system has four levels. Plugin definition, derivatives, configuration and finally the run-time instance.

As you can see in your error message you configure a specific plugin definition or a derivative of the plugin definition. This definition is static and you can't change it after you have configured it.

Only the run-time instance of the plugin can react on dynamic conditions like the active domain.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to figure out how to extend `MenuBlock` using only `create()`. I had to change to a `__construct()` and `create()` system, and returned `static()` from within `create()` while manually injecting the dependencies from both the `MenuBlock` and `SystemMenuBlock` classes. This is a bit less robust in that it will break if the `MenuBlock` class ever changes dependencies, however it still accomplishes the intended behavior of using an injected dependency within `getDerivitiveId()`:

```
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, MenuLinkTreeInterface $menu_tree, MenuActiveTrailInterface $menu_active_trail, MenuParentFormSelectorInterface $menu_parent_form_selector, EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, DomainNegotiatorInterface $domain_negotiator) {
    $this->domainNegotiator = $domain_negotiator;
    $this->menuParentFormSelector = $menu_parent_form_selector;
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $menu_tree, $menu_active_trail);
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('menu.link_tree'),
      $container->get('menu.active_trail'),
      $container->get('menu.parent_form_selector'),
      $container->get('entity_type.manager'),
      $container->get('domain.negotiator'));
  }
```